# After closing p:dialog, event="dialogReturn" is not being called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, event-handling

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2. Scenario:

1. Open a dialog to see the list
2. On dialog, show actions column at the end
3. Close the dialog
4. Redirect to selected action page in the column.

1, 2, 3 are working.

I have tried many things, but redirecting after closing it not working. `dialogReturn` method is not being called where I am calling the redirect code.

Here I am successfully loading a dialog in MyFile.xhtml.

```
<p:commandLink action="#{userDashboardBacking.showPriorityMyView()}"
                  class="myClass"
                  value="#{userDashboardBacking.priorityFilesLabel1} (#{userDashboardBacking.priorityFilesCount1})">
                  <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="@form" listener="#{userDashboardBacking.dialogReturn()}" />
    </p:commandLink>
```

MyFileBacking.java

```
// this always get me to the required dialog/page
public void showPriorityMyView(){
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("closable", true);
    options.put("draggable", true);
    options.put("resizable", true);

    options.put("contentHeight", "500");
    options.put("contentWidth", "1100");

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("priorityMyView", options, null);
}

// this method is never called.
public void dialogReturn(){
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String  outcome = "/myDetails.jsf?faces-redirect=true"; 
    facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext, null,outcome );
}
```

MyDetailDlg.xhtml

```
<p:column width="10">
    <h:commandLink update="@form" action="#{myViewDlgBacking.selectedFileIdForDetails(row.fileId)}" title="View Details" immediate="true"
                        styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" />
</p:column>
```

MyViewDlgBacking.java

```
// successfully closes the dialogue.
public void selectedFileIdForDetails(Long itemId){
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(0);
}
```

Why is `dialogReturn` not being called and how can I redirect to another page after closing the dialog?

Comment: in your dialogReturn() method you can directly return the url like
return "myDetails?faces-redirect=true";

Comment: I could, But that method is not executed when dialog is closed. If I write redirect code in the selectedFileIdForDetails, where dialog is being closed, then the redirected page opens in the dialog box

Comment: Have you printed any logs at `dialogReturn` function?

Answer (score 0):

Change to java method without '()'

```
<p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="@form" listener="#{userDashboardBacking.dialogReturn}" />
```

and add SelectEvent as input parameter to your method

```
public void dialogReturn(SelectEvent event){
    Long selectedId = (Long) event.getObject();
}
```

Comment: Adding SelectEvent makes no difference. DF in PF6 supports both.